# invalid command name "cat". expect send [ ] at shell script

Tags: shell, expect

I want to use expect at shell script

My code is here

```
#!/bin/sh

expect << EOF
send [cat hello]
EOF
```

This command is failed

> invalid command name "cat"
>
> while executing "cat hello"
>
> invoked from within "send [cat hello]"

but, send [cat hello] command successed in expect prompt

```
expect1.1> send [cat hello]
world
expect1.2>
```

Why do I output the different execution results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inside `expect` shell:**

While you are in `expect` shell and whenever any executable shell command is given, that will be executed and as if like you have executed it in terminal normally.

```
expect1.1> ls
A  B  C  D
expect1.2> cat A
I am A

expect1.3> pwd
/home/dinesh/test
expect1.4>
```

If you have keep them inside square brackets like `[cat A]`, unlike a normal command call, still it will execute shell command and returns empty string.

```
expect1.4> set val [cat A]
I am A

expect1.5> puts "->$val<-"
-><-
expect1.6>
```

If you add a procedure which is having a name equivalent as that of any shell command, then only the corresponding command will be called.

```
expect1.6> proc cat {input} {
+> return "you passed $input\n"
+> }
expect1.7> cat A
you passed A

expect1.8> cat
wrong # args: should be "cat input"
    while executing
"cat "
expect1.9> send [cat A]
you passed A
expect1.10>
```

Unless `spawn_id` is set (by means of spawning any program), `Expect` will always expect and send commands to the `stdin` and `stdout` respectively.

```
expect1.11> exp_internal 1
expect1.12> expect hai

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "hai"? no
```

As you can see in the debug output, `exp0` points to the `stdin` only.

**When `expect` program called**

When `expect` program is called explicitly, at that time, in order to execute any shell command, you have to use `exec` command, else you will get the `invalid command name error` message.

```
expect << EOF
 send [exec cat hello]
EOF
```

**Output :**

```
[dinesh@lab test]$ ./baek.sh
I am A
[dinesh@lab test]$
```

**Now, why this difference ?**

Technically, when you are using `expect` shell, you are allowed with the feature of executing shell command in there itself.